# vue emit once on multiple

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm using Vue for my webpage, then I use eventBus to pass data component to other components.

I want to know,

1. passing data with eventBus between sibling component is a bad pattern.
2. eventBus.$emit once, and eventBus.$on at multiple components.

I found some articles that you need to pass with props when parent - child situation.

Also, I cannot found about mutitle "on" situation.

here's sample architecture.

- dashboard

  - component1
  - component2

dashboard contains component1 and 2

case no 1.

passing data component1 -> component2 to use eventBus is good pattern?

case no 2.

at dashboard, I emit eventBus.$emit('update', some data)

then,

at component 1,2 I listen event with eventBus.$on('update', (data) => ... )

this pattern is good pattern?

Comment: can you explain me why are you still using event bus instead of vuex?

Comment: This pattern is a good pattern **if** your scenario is exactly as you describe (just a couple of components, just a couple of event types). Otherwise, the eventBus may begin to go too complicated and vuex starts to be a better alternative.

Comment: @mending3 I didn't use it,, but coworker use event-bus pattern at that situation.
Do I need to change that works to vuex?

Comment: @acdcjunior thanks for response. at case2, that one is also a good pattern?

Comment: just use vuex right away. event bus was just good old days. vuex is successor for event bus with fairly huge features and support compared to event bus

Comment: case2 is the same, if that's all you got, it simple enough to pass. But, another thing, you actually seem to have shared state (the `data` you pass on the events) not just "distribuited notification". If it were the latter, the event bus would be ok, even in a more complex scenario. But if your case is shared state, then vuex can be a better/cleaner solution even if the scenario is very simple (after all, adding vuex is not that much of a hurdle these days...)

Comment: Event bus is a good pattern - when you need to signal **events**. You may have multiple subscribers for a single emitter, and single subscriber for multiple emitters. Vuex can not help in this situation. However, when you need reactivity and want to modify and then track the same variables from inside multiple components - Vuex is more suitable. In essence, Vuex is just one very large plain old JavaScript object and a few handy helpers. So - both patterns have their purpose and usefulness.

Comment: In general, communicating directly between sibling components can get messy. It's better to communicate only between direct parent and child. If siblings need to communicate, can the parent facilitate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do everything with Vuex and that would be a cleaner solution, since in your storage you will be more aware of your data flow.

In case 1 you can commit a mutation and then in all places needed watch for changes or better, just use computed values. EventBus is not bad pattern, but I think it's more suitable for big distributed projects, where you really want to propagate events, not just pass data updates.

For case 2 you don't need anything but Vue. Just pass parameters and watch them in children components.